# How concerning is javascript compatability in 2017?

Tags: javascript, compatibility

I recently found an awesome little tool to test my javascript code compatibility: http://jscc.info/

Now, my question is in regards to a few of the compatibility percentages some bits of my code received.

Here is the code I am checking (just for an example):

```
var myapp_separate = '1';
var myapp_source_direct = '1';
var myapp_source_organic = '2';
var myapp_source_referral = '3';
var myapp_redirect_url = 'http://myapp.dev/thanks';
var myapp_redirect_data = '1';

// handle form submission
document.getElementById('myapp_form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // set source_id based on cookie
    if (myapp_get_cookie('myapp_source_id')) {
        document.getElementById('source_id').value = myapp_get_cookie('myapp_source_id');
    }
    else if (myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium') && myapp_separate === '1') {
        if (myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium') === 'Direct') {
            document.getElementById('source_id').value = myapp_source_direct;
        }
        else if (myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium') === 'Organic') {
            document.getElementById('source_id').value = myapp_source_organic;
        }
        else if (myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium') === 'Referral') {
            document.getElementById('source_id').value = myapp_source_referral;
        }
    }

    // set referrer values
    document.getElementById('referrer_medium').value = myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium');
    document.getElementById('referrer_keyword').value = myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_keyword');
    document.getElementById('referrer_url').value = myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_url');

    // send post
    var form = document.getElementById('myapp_form');
    var form_data = new FormData(form);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open(form.method, form.action);
    request.send(form_data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var error_groups = document.getElementsByClassName('has-error');
            for (var i = 0; i < error_groups.length; i++) error_groups[i].classList.remove('has-error');

            if (response.status === 'Error') {
                // errors, highlight form groups & alert
                var errors = [];
                for (var key in response.errors) {
                    if (response.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        var form_group = myapp_find_ancestor(document.getElementById(key), 'form-group');
                        if (form_group) form_group.classList.add('has-error');
                        errors.push(response.errors[key]);
                    }
                }
                alert(errors.join("\n"));
            }
            else {
                // success, redirect
                var url = myapp_redirect_url;
                if (myapp_redirect_data === '1') url += '?' + myapp_serialize(form);
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        }
    };
});

// set referrer cookies
if (!myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium')) {
    var document_referrer = document.referrer;

    if (myapp_get_param('source_id', window.location.href)) {
        myapp_set_cookie('myapp_source_id', myapp_get_param('source_id', window.location.href));
        myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium', 'None');
        myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_url', window.location.href);
    }
    else if (!document_referrer) {
        myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium', 'Direct');
    }
    else {
        var referrer_url = new URL(document_referrer);
        var referrer_hostname = referrer_url.hostname;
        var organic_referrers = [['about', 'terms'], ['alice', 'qs'], ['alltheweb', 'q'], ['altavista', 'q'], ['aol', 'encquery'], ['aol', 'q'], ['aol', 'query'], ['ask', 'q'], ['baidu', 'wd'], ['bing', 'q'], ['cnn', 'query'], ['daum', 'q'], ['ekolay', 'q'], ['eniro', 'search_word'], ['google', 'q'], ['kvasir', 'q'], ['lycos', 'query'], ['mamma', 'query'], ['msn', 'q'], ['mynet', 'q'], ['najdi', 'q'], ['naver', 'query'], ['netscape', 'query'], ['onetcenter', 'qt'], ['ozu', 'q'], ['pchome', 'q'], ['rambler', 'words'], ['search', 'q'], ['sesam', 'q'], ['seznam', 'q'], ['szukacz', 'q'], ['terra', 'query'], ['virgilio', 'qs'], ['voila', 'rdata'], ['wp', 'szukaj'], ['yahoo', 'p'], ['yam', 'k'], ['yandex', 'text']];

        for (var i = 0; i < organic_referrers.length; i++) {
            if (referrer_hostname.indexOf(organic_referrers[i][0]) !== -1 && myapp_get_param(organic_referrers[i][1], document_referrer)) {
                myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium', 'Organic');
                myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_keyword', myapp_get_param(organic_referrers[i][1], document_referrer));
            }
        }

        if (!myapp_get_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium')) {
            myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_medium', 'Referral');
        }

        myapp_set_cookie('myapp_referrer_url', document_referrer);
    }
}

// get cookie
function myapp_get_cookie(key) {
    var value = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return value ? value[2] : null;
}

// set cookie
function myapp_set_cookie(key, value) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

// get url param
function myapp_get_param(key, href) {
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex_s = "[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regex_s);
    var results = regex.exec(href);
    return results ? results[1] : null;
}

// find ancestor
function myapp_find_ancestor(element, class_name) {
    while ((element = element.parentElement) && !element.classList.contains(class_name));
    return element;
}

// serialize form data
function myapp_serialize(form) {
    var field, s = [];
    if (typeof form === 'object' && form.nodeName === 'FORM') {
        for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
            field = form.elements[i];
            if (field.name && !field.disabled && field.type !== 'file' && field.type !== 'reset' && field.type !== 'submit' && field.type !== 'button') {
                if (field.type === 'select-multiple') {
                    for (j = form.elements[i].options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        if (field.options[j].selected) s[s.length] = encodeURIComponent(field.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(field.options[j].value);
                    }
                }
                else if ((field.type !== 'checkbox' && field.type !== 'radio') || field.checked) {
                    s[s.length] = encodeURIComponent(field.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(field.value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');
}
```

Here are some of the notices I got, and the percentages for each, as well as my thoughts:

Array.prototype.indexOf - Full support (97.4% global browser share) - **this looks OK**

classList (DOMTokenList) - Full support (77.2% global browser share) - **this is concerning**

EventTarget (addEventListener) - Full support (97.5% global browser share) - **this looks OK**

getElementsByClassName - Full support (97.5% global browser share) - **this looks OK**

JSON parsing - Full support (97.9% global browser share) - **this looks OK**

XMLHttpRequest advanced features - Full support (76.2% global browser share) - **this is concerning**

Now as I mentioned, I'm a little concerned with the following:

**classList (DOMTokenList) - Full support (77.2% global browser share)**

**XMLHttpRequest advanced features - Full support (76.2% global browser share)**

Some of the browsers it mentions with "partial support" (which is around 15% for each) seem to be pretty old and I can't imagine are used very often.

Should I be rewriting my code in order to increase the percentages for each of these methods? Or should I not be worried at all?

Thanks for your time and help with this issue.

Comment: "Global browsers" isn't very helpful. You need to check what browsers your users are using. Its likely that >99% of your users are on IE11 or better. So that `classList` is more likely to be at >99% support for your visitors. .

Comment: this is usually the place to check for compatibility
https://caniuse.com/

Furthermore, a percentage of total browsers out there is not as valid as what percentage of browsers your users have.

Comment: @derp The site I mentioned actually lets you paste your javascript code then parses it and tells you global browser compatability, rather than having to check things 1 by 1. My users will vary enormously as this code will be used on public websites.

Comment: hmm i would recommend putting google analytics on there and letting it run for a while. This should tell you a rough breakdown of the types of browsers your users have. The site is cool though

Comment: Yeah that's definately a good suggestion. However, this is more of a curiosity for pushing this live without having to gather months worth of data first. I just want to make sure at least 97% of all visitors will have browsers capable of running my javascript without having to analyze Analytics data.

Comment: According to the github project, he uses the caniuse website. I didn't took time to check the code how he determines the result, but I do have checked your code. My experience tells me that your code will run fine in 95% of the situation. Only if a visitor visits your site with IE < 11 or Opera Mini, they will experience problems. But that is a fairly negligible share of people that doesn't outweigh the effort to implement support for this (in this situation only ofc. It really depends of the code !)